Сравнение временных рядов
Занимаюсь определением накрутки просмотров в Telegram. При сборе данных заметил, что почти все обычные ряды просмотров под постами имеют похожие графики, только масштабы различные. Таким образом я хочу, построив эталонный временной ряд, определять накрутку.
На данный момент вижу две проблемы:

Составление эталонного графика для всех постов, то есть чтобы масштаб не играл роли
Способ сравнения эталонного графика с произвольным

Какие методы можете предложить для решения данных проблем?
P.S. под рядом просмотров подразумеваю временной ряд, характеризующий зависимость прироста кол-ва просмотров под постом за час
Привожу пример возможных графиков:
Нормальный пост:
Данные(первое число - временная метка, второе - приращение просмотров за час):
[(0, 257), (1, 84), (2, 28), (3, 21), (4, 20), (5, 19), (6, 11), (7, 10), (8, 10), (9, 11), (10, 5), (11, 3), (12, 1), (13, 2), (14, 0), (15, 2), (16, 3), (17, 4), (18, 6), (19, 7), (20, 4), (21, 2), (22, 9), (23, 7), (24, 4), (25, 1), (26, 3), (27, 5), (28, 2), (29, 2), (30, 6), (31, 3), (32, 1), (33, 5), (34, 1), (35, 0), (36, 1), (37, 1), (38, 0), (39, 0), (40, 0), (41, 4), (42, 0), (43, 2), (44, 4), (45, 4), (46, 2), (47, 1), (48, 1), (49, 2), (50, 2), (51, 6), (52, 33), (53, 9), (54, 10), (55, 1), (56, 6), (57, 1), (58, 3), (59, 0), (60, 1), (61, 3), (62, 1), (63, 1), (64, 3), (65, 2), (66, 2), (67, 3), (68, 2), (69, 2), (70, 1), (71, 2), (72, 0), (73, 5), (74, 1), (75, 1), (76, 2), (77, 2), (78, 2), (79, 1), (80, 4), (81, 4), (82, 2), (83, 0), (84, 1), (85, 1), (86, 1), (87, 1), (88, 1), (89, 1), (90, 0), (91, 1), (92, 4), (93, 1), (94, 2), (95, 2), (96, 2), (97, 4), (98, 1), (99, 0), (100, 2), (101, 0), (102, 2), (103, 2), (104, 0), (105, 2), (106, 1), (107, 2), (108, 0), (109, 1), (110, 0), (111, 4), (112, 1), (113, 2), (114, 4), (115, 3), (116, 3), (117, 0), (118, 3), (119, 0), (120, 0), (121, 2), (122, 6), (123, 3), (124, 2), (125, 2), (126, 3), (127, 2), (128, 0)]

Накрученные просмотры:
Данные:
[(0, 13089), (1, 161), (2, 125), (3, 81), (4, 43), (5, 32), (6, 17), (7, 15), (8, 19), (9, 17), (10, 31), (11, 33), (12, 32), (13, 36), (14, 22), (15, 12), (16, 24), (17, 27), (18, 39), (19, 19), (20, 12), (21, 15), (22, 14), (23, 34), (24, 13), (25, 12), (26, 10), (27, 9), (28, 5), (29, 1), (30, 3), (31, 1), (32, 2), (33, 4), (34, 3), (35, 6), (36, 4), (37, 8), (38, 2), (39, 3), (40, 4), (41, 28), (42, 8), (43, 7), (44, 9), (45, 3), (46, 2), (47, 2), (48, 62), (49, 32), (50, 40), (51, 0), (52, 8), (53, 10), (54, 0), (55, 5), (56, 1), (57, 2), (58, 4), (59, 10), (60, 6), (61, 3), (62, 19), (63, 16), (64, 19), (65, 37), (66, 7), (67, 8), (68, 20), (69, 7), (70, 4), (71, 9), (72, 33)]

Данные:
[(0, 719), (1, 629), (2, 607), (3, 609), (4, 605), (5, 608), (6, 620), (7, 610), (8, 620), (9, 636), (10, 619), (11, 635), (12, 601), (13, 563), (14, 558), (15, 548), (16, 557), (17, 570), (18, 550), (19, 557), (20, 564), (21, 572), (22, 593), (23, 593), (24, 427), (25, 623), (26, 638), (27, 503), (28, 597), (29, 11), (30, 0), (31, 0), (32, 2), (33, 0), (34, 2), (35, 14), (36, 5), (37, 3), (38, 1), (39, 3), (40, 6), (41, 8), (42, 5), (43, 6), (44, 1), (45, 2), (46, 2), (47, 1), (48, 2), (49, 2), (50, 1), (51, 0), (52, 0), (53, 1), (54, 0), (55, 0), (56, 0), (57, 0), (58, 2), (59, 1), (60, 3), (61, 2), (62, 0), (63, 1), (64, 3), (65, 2), (66, 0), (67, 3), (68, 2), (69, 2), (70, 0), (71, 1), (72, 1), (73, 3), (74, 1), (75, 3), (76, 0), (77, 1), (78, 3), (79, 2), (80, 1), (81, 4), (82, 2), (83, 4), (84, 0), (85, 9), (86, 2), (87, 1), (88, 5), (89, 1), (90, 2), (91, 4), (92, 2), (93, 5)]

Ещё один пример:


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Проще мне кажется искать аномалии на графиках, а не искать эталон и с ним сравнивать. Приведите в вопросе примеры графиков - нормальных и накрученных. Чтобы было о чём разговаривать.

Хм, интересно. А прямо числовыми рядами (в виде текста) можете добавить примеры? )  Тут прямо хочется прологарифмировать и ещё раз после этого графики посмотреть, например. И в плане аномалий тут "ступеньку" надо как-то ловить, тут готовые методы, боюсь, не помогут, тут эмпирику какую-то надо придумывать. Ну и посмотреть, что будет если делить текущее значение ряда на следующее ещё, например (чтобы не делить на ноль - везде прибавлять 1). Ряд со ступенькой тут опять же должен выделяться.

тут подойдёт какое-нибудь простое правило: в тот день, когда накопительный счётчик голосов достиг 80%, дневной счётчик этого дня не должен превышать 40% от дневного максимума (т.е., от кол-ва голосов в первый день)

а разве она его не решает?  80% достигнуто на 24-ый день, и дневной счётчик этого дня превышает 40% максимума, значит накрутка.  если есть ещё и другие непохожие графики, несите их сюда )))

@desire - меньше трёпа, больше цифр!  приведите пример хоть одой реальной накрутки, которая не ловится моим правилом

числа не буду приводить - нужно привести числа, причём реальные, а не выдуманные.  конечно, для любого конкретного способа, наперёд зная этот способ, можно придумать "умную накрутку", которая его обойдёт. но существует ли в реальности накрутка, которая, не зная моего способа, уже обходит его?  я думаю, что нет.  мой способ пытается отличить нормальное распределение ("колокол") от ненормального (прямоугольник, треугольник).

Все понимают что можно сделать накрутку неотличимую от реального процесса? То есть, задачу можно ставить только так: вот есть случайный процесс, вот есть набор статистических гипотез, выбираете наилучшую, даёте ответ. Но ещё раз, любое решение можно обмануть, накручивая с подходящим распределением.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Ну это как с выборами. В теории, если захотеть, можно скрыть любые фальсификации. Но по факту мы до сих пор видим красивые графики Шпилькина.

накрутка, неотличимая от реального процесса, должна быть бесконечно долгой по времени.  на практике накрутка завершается через несколько дней, и старые посты больше не накручивают

Ну вот например простая эвристика.
data = [
    [(0, 257), (1, 84), (2, 28), (3, 21), (4, 20), (5, 19), (6, 11), (7, 10), (8, 10), (9, 11), (10, 5), (11, 3), (12, 1), (13, 2), (14, 0), (15, 2), (16, 3), (17, 4), (18, 6), (19, 7), (20, 4), (21, 2), (22, 9), (23, 7), (24, 4), (25, 1), (26, 3), (27, 5), (28, 2), (29, 2), (30, 6), (31, 3), (32, 1), (33, 5), (34, 1), (35, 0), (36, 1), (37, 1), (38, 0), (39, 0), (40, 0), (41, 4), (42, 0), (43, 2), (44, 4), (45, 4), (46, 2), (47, 1), (48, 1), (49, 2), (50, 2), (51, 6), (52, 33), (53, 9), (54, 10), (55, 1), (56, 6), (57, 1), (58, 3), (59, 0), (60, 1), (61, 3), (62, 1), (63, 1), (64, 3), (65, 2), (66, 2), (67, 3), (68, 2), (69, 2), (70, 1), (71, 2), (72, 0), (73, 5), (74, 1), (75, 1), (76, 2), (77, 2), (78, 2), (79, 1), (80, 4), (81, 4), (82, 2), (83, 0), (84, 1), (85, 1), (86, 1), (87, 1), (88, 1), (89, 1), (90, 0), (91, 1), (92, 4), (93, 1), (94, 2), (95, 2), (96, 2), (97, 4), (98, 1), (99, 0), (100, 2), (101, 0), (102, 2), (103, 2), (104, 0), (105, 2), (106, 1), (107, 2), (108, 0), (109, 1), (110, 0), (111, 4), (112, 1), (113, 2), (114, 4), (115, 3), (116, 3), (117, 0), (118, 3), (119, 0), (120, 0), (121, 2), (122, 6), (123, 3), (124, 2), (125, 2), (126, 3), (127, 2), (128, 0)],
    [(0, 13089), (1, 161), (2, 125), (3, 81), (4, 43), (5, 32), (6, 17), (7, 15), (8, 19), (9, 17), (10, 31), (11, 33), (12, 32), (13, 36), (14, 22), (15, 12), (16, 24), (17, 27), (18, 39), (19, 19), (20, 12), (21, 15), (22, 14), (23, 34), (24, 13), (25, 12), (26, 10), (27, 9), (28, 5), (29, 1), (30, 3), (31, 1), (32, 2), (33, 4), (34, 3), (35, 6), (36, 4), (37, 8), (38, 2), (39, 3), (40, 4), (41, 28), (42, 8), (43, 7), (44, 9), (45, 3), (46, 2), (47, 2), (48, 62), (49, 32), (50, 40), (51, 0), (52, 8), (53, 10), (54, 0), (55, 5), (56, 1), (57, 2), (58, 4), (59, 10), (60, 6), (61, 3), (62, 19), (63, 16), (64, 19), (65, 37), (66, 7), (67, 8), (68, 20), (69, 7), (70, 4), (71, 9), (72, 33)],
    [(0, 719), (1, 629), (2, 607), (3, 609), (4, 605), (5, 608), (6, 620), (7, 610), (8, 620), (9, 636), (10, 619), (11, 635), (12, 601), (13, 563), (14, 558), (15, 548), (16, 557), (17, 570), (18, 550), (19, 557), (20, 564), (21, 572), (22, 593), (23, 593), (24, 427), (25, 623), (26, 638), (27, 503), (28, 597), (29, 11), (30, 0), (31, 0), (32, 2), (33, 0), (34, 2), (35, 14), (36, 5), (37, 3), (38, 1), (39, 3), (40, 6), (41, 8), (42, 5), (43, 6), (44, 1), (45, 2), (46, 2), (47, 1), (48, 2), (49, 2), (50, 1), (51, 0), (52, 0), (53, 1), (54, 0), (55, 0), (56, 0), (57, 0), (58, 2), (59, 1), (60, 3), (61, 2), (62, 0), (63, 1), (64, 3), (65, 2), (66, 0), (67, 3), (68, 2), (69, 2), (70, 0), (71, 1), (72, 1), (73, 3), (74, 1), (75, 3), (76, 0), (77, 1), (78, 3), (79, 2), (80, 1), (81, 4), (82, 2), (83, 4), (84, 0), (85, 9), (86, 2), (87, 1), (88, 5), (89, 1), (90, 2), (91, 4), (92, 2), (93, 5)]
]

for d in data:
    y = [i[1] for i in d]
    m = max(max(a, b) / (min(a, b) + 1) for a, b in zip(y, y[1:]))
    print(f'max div = {m}')    

Вывод:
max div = 5.0
max div = 80.79629629629629
max div = 49.75

Что я собственно смотрю - насколько большой был скачок вверх или вниз, т.е. ищу тот самый "порожек", который я ранее заприметил. Я беру xi и xi+1, делю большее из них на меньшее и ищу максимум этой величины по всем i. Какое выбрать значение для отсечения накруток от не накруток - смотрите по остальным данным. По предоставленным данным можно и 10 взять и 20, например. Если меньше этого числа, то считаем, что без накруток, если больше - с накрутками.
Но это очень простая эвристика, можно придумать что-то сложнее, но нужно больше данных для этого.

Задача очень интересная. (Конечно, сравнивать надо не графики, а сами временные ряды).  Мне кажется, она сводиться к задачам, которыми занимаются в разделах классификации (это если у вас имеются все или большинство шаблоны аномального поведения значений ряда) или кластеризации временных рядов. Там в общем-то разработано несколько интересных решений. Интересно было бы даже посмотреть как они сработают на вашей задаче.
Для примера, можно ознакомиться с более-менее текущим положением дел в этих областях. Там прикладные задачи конечно другие. Но методы переносятся в вашу прикладную область достаточно прозрачно.
https://towardsdatascience.com/a-brief-introduction-to-time-series-classification-algorithms-7b4284d31b97
https://towardsdatascience.com/k-nn-based-time-series-classification-e5d761d01ea2
https://www.storybench.org/how-to-use-hierarchical-cluster-analysis-on-time-series-data/
https://towardsdatascience.com/hands-on-climate-time-series-clustering-using-machine-learning-with-python-6a12ce1607f9
https://pub.towardsai.net/highly-comparative-time-series-analysis-a-paper-review-5b51d14a291c
https://habr.com/ru/companies/otus/articles/721026/
P.S. А данные у вас свои или откуда-то из открытых источников получены?


На данный момент вижу две проблемы:
Составление эталонного графика для всех постов, то есть чтобы масштаб
не играл роли
Способ сравнения эталонного графика с произвольным Какие
методы можете предложить для решения данных проблем?

для п.1 - можно стандартизировать/нормализовать данные
для п.2 - вычесть среднее, чтобы сравнивать тренд и дисперсию по остаткам
